# Vlookup based on format

Tags: excel, vlookup

Purely excel query here.

My lookup table has values that have special formatting,
example

| Code | Variant name |
| --- | --- |
| 000 | No sub Variant |

the code that am using is this
`VLOOKUP((MID(A2,13,3),'[New Variant Name.xlsx]Legend for New Variant Number'!$K$5:$L$49,2,FALSE)`

`Output of MID(A2,13,3) is 000`
but the vlookup always gives #N/A,

In the table if you check the value of `code (000) in formula bar, u get 0.`
and the `corresponding cell in the lookup table is 0` that is why vlookup is failing,  so what can be done here? any suggestions?

I have checked the obvious and that didnt work either,
 `VLOOKUP(if((MID(A2,13,3)= 0,Text(0,000),MID(A2,13,3)),'[New Variant Name.xlsx]Legend for New Variant Number'!$K$5:$L$49,2,FALSE)`

Any ideas on how to progress? Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you see in the formula bar if you select `A2`?  What do you see in the formula bar if you select the matching cell in column `K` of your table?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld in the formula bar `A2` shows `UPE00819-YCU000-NA` in and for matching cell in column 'K' in the formula bar it shows `0`

Comment: @FaneDuru, sorry for pulling u into this query, but do u have any pointers as to which direction I can go?

Comment: You have not supplied enough sample data to be sure, but if the "matching cell" might be a number instead of a text string, then replace `lookup_value` with `IFERROR(--MID(A2,13,3),MID(A2,13,3))`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, this works, could you please post this as an answer, so that I can vote this up??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not supplied enough sample data to be sure, but if the "matching cell" might be a number instead of a text string, then replace `lookup_value` with

```
IFERROR(--MID(A2,13,3),MID(A2,13,3))
```

*Not Tested:*

```
VLOOKUP((IFERROR(--MID(A2,13,3),MID(A2,13,3)),'[New Variant Name.xlsx]Legend for New Variant Number'!$K$5:$L$49,2,FALSE)
```